# Get full path of an uploaded file jsp

Tags: file, jsp, upload, path

I have a form in which I upload a file. Until here, it's okay. But then I need to get the uploaded file's full path but I have no idea how to do it. I've searched a lot but still, nothing. Can anyone help me? Please? Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache commons io, you can use the `FilenameUtils` class.
The `getFullPath` method should return what you need. However, I think that for some security reasons some browsers may change the path